# TypeError: path.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack

```
/node_modules/webpack/lib/TemplatedPathPlugin.js:72
        .replace(REGEXP_HASH, withHashLength(getReplacer(data.hash), data.hashWithLength))
         ^
```

I'm getting this error when running `webpack` - it seems that `path` is an object rather than a string, and the replace method is therefore not found. Can anyone shed light on this error? Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var basePath = 'app';
var outputFile = 'output.js';

var config = {

    entry: basePath + '/index.js',

    output: {
        path: basePath,
        filename: outputFile
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: I think you have to export your config : module.exports = require('webpack.config.js')

Comment: [Docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path) "output.path The output directory as absolute path (required)."

Answer (score 11):

Check your plugin configuration. Webpack 2 changes the ExtractTextPlugin slightly. It expects all parameters to come wrapped in an object, so your first parameter is now the value of `filename` on that object rather than a string.

Webpack 1 way:
`new ExtractTextPlugin('[hash].css', {allChunks: true, disable: false}),`

Webpack 2 way:
`new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: '[hash].css', allChunks: true, disable: false}),`

More info in the [README](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to track down the issue is by giving `console.log(path)` on file `/node_modules/webpack/lib/TemplatedPathPlugin.js`.

I got same error recently -- then I went to that file and modify the `replacePathVariables` function:

`function replacePathVariables(path, data) {
    console.log(' ---> ', path)
    var chunk = data.chunk;
    var chunkId = chunk && chunk.id;`

I found out that I was accidentally set `output.publicPath` option with array:

`output: {
   publicPath: ['/dist/']
}`

Instead of (string):

`output: {
   publicPath: '/dist/'
}`